# What's an alternative to the hamburger menu icon for a college newspaper's mobile website?

Tags: usability, mobile, menu

I am designing a weekly college newspaper's mobile website interface. The newspaper is comprised of a number of subsections: creative, commentary, on campus, etc.

The design is based on a block system in which each section is given a separate block in which all articles in their respective sections from each week's issue are displayed.

I am trying to avoid using the 'hamburger menu' to allow readers to immediately navigate to their section of interest, but am at a loss as to how to allow readers to quickly navigate the website without a sidebar menu. I am considering removing the menu functionality entirely to encourage readers to scroll down the page (there are only ~20 articles released every week).

Are there any other suggestions regarding alternatives to the traditional hamburger menu system?

Comment: Please do a search http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=hamburger for many questions related to this topic. Also, your title and description are different things, not to mention extremely broad and bound to opinionated answers. Try to restrict your question by identifying your problem first, then add more info about it (mocks, images and such) so you can get a real answer

Comment: @Devin If it's a duplicate, please mark it as such. Future visitors are confused.

Comment: @JonathanAllard, nice to know you can see the future and confusion on people that didn't even visit the site yet ;) . Either way, this comment was part of the *close* process, question wasn't closed because it didn't get enough votes to be closed, so you're probably barking at the wrong tree . But thank you for your suggestion anyways.

Comment: @Devin Sorry if I was rude, I just get snippy when I end up on a question and someone says it's a duplicate without saying where to go. I can't see the future but I can see the present which is the future of the past, and I was one of those confused visitors from the future of the past. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think its OK to show blocks corresponding to categories on the home page.
When the user taps one, it drills down to all articles in that category. Maybe include a breadcrumbs style navigation on the top for a quick return to the homepage.

Im writing this under presumption that the only content on your webpage are articles.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

Also, a really good tip for any mobile website.